# Jetzt seid ihr Kerle an der Reihe

Tags: grammar-identification

> Jetzt seid **ihr Kerle** an der Reihe.

Is the bolded phrase an apposition phrase?

Comment: Where did you find this slightly odd sentence? In case it is a direct translation from US-American ("you guys"): this is not how you express things in German, even not in slang.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann It would be possible, for example in a sentence like "Wir Mädels haben es schon gemacht, jetzt seid ihr Kerle an der Reihe".

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Yes, it is possible to think of (rare) situations where the sentence could be used. However, this does not answer my question (where did he find that sentence) and my concern that at the root of the original question might be a bad translation.from English.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/ihr+Kerle

Comment: @ughitudhi   Thank you for the link to this list of sentences with *ihr Kerle* plus their equivalents in English with *you guys*. This actually confirms my suspicion that this sentence probably originates in a (too literal) translation from (very common) English *you guys* to (rather uncommon) German *ihr Kerle*. I am not saying that in real-life German you will never hear *ihr Kerle*, but such occassions are really, really rare; whereas *you guys* is one of the most frequent expressions in English/American colloquial language.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Thank you, Is there any other expression in german, which resembles "you guys"

Answer (score 4):

No. It's just the subject. In German subjects can stand at any position within the sentence. Very often they occupy position 1 (like in English):

> Ihr Kerle seid jetzt an der Reihe.

But other positions are possible too, like in your example. (The full set of rules about German word order is long and complicated and not topic of your question.)

The phrase **»ihr Kerle«** is the subject of the sentence. It is a nominal group, this is the name for a part of speech that consists of a noun (therefore "nominal") to which there are some other words attached that build a group that is one part of speech. Here, in your example, verb and subject are in second person. More often you see third person, so lets have a look at some third person versions:

> Jetzt sind **die Kerle** an der Reihe.
>   Jetzt sind **diese Kerle** an der Reihe.
>   Jetzt sind **andere Kerle** an der Reihe.

What is marked bold are nominal groups that are used as subject. They all consist of a noun (*Kerle* = guys) and a determiner (*die = the, diese = these, andere = other*). You find [determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) in [English grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) as well as in [German grammar](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)). They can be articles, pronouns, quantifiers and many more.

The cases, where you can use a noun as a subject without a determiner are rare. At the moment I just can remember names (»Klaus schläft«) and indefinite plurals (»Planeten sind rund«) to be allowed to appear without determiner as a subject. The standard case is, that the subject is a nominal group, which means, it needs a determiner.

Let's go back to second person.

When you want to use any noun to be the subject of a sentence in second person, then it is always determined. You can't speak to just any persons. You always speak to certain persons. And this means, you have to use a determiner, and the only word I can think of to be used in such a case is the personal pronoun *»ihr«.* You have the same construction in English too, but the german phrase »an der Reihe sein« converts to another grammatical construction when translated into English ("du bist an der Reihe" is literally: "you are on the row", but in correct English "it's your turn"), so I use another example to demonstrate it:

> **You guys** should leave my pub now.
>   **Ihr Kerle** solltet jetzt mein Pub verlassen.

In German (but not in English) alternative other word orders are allowed:

> Jetzt solltet **ihr Kerle** mein Pub verlassen.
>   Mein Pub solltet **ihr Kerle** jetzt verlassen.

Of course, you also can use an apposition phrase in such a case, but it looks different:

> **You, dear guys,** should leave my pub now.
>   **Ihr, liebe Kerle,** solltet jetzt mein Pub verlassen.

Comment: How can a noun be the subject of *seid*? Why don't you consider *ihr* to be the subject? After all, leaving out *Kerle* leaves the sentence unchanged but removing *ihr* forces third person agreement: *Kerle sind an der Reihe*.

Comment: The head of the NP _ihr Kerle_ cannot be _Kerle_. Otherwise, _sein_ could not be in second person _(seid)_. In this regard, this case is diametrically opposed to your _Jetzt sind die Kerle/diese Kerle/andere Kerle an der Reihe_ examples.

Comment: @Hubert Sagt man in Österreich **das** Pub? (Ich weiß, dass es einige Worte gibt, die in D und Ö einen unterschiedlichen Genus haben). Ich war schon drauf und dran, Deinen Beitrag zu editieren und in *mein**en** Pub* zu korrigieren

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Ja. Es heißt **das** Beisl, **das** Gasthaus, **das** Café, **das** Restaurant und daher auch **das** Pub. Ich habe gegoogelt: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pub) findet, dass neben "**das** Pub" (erste Wahl) auch "**der** Pub" (zweite Wahl) ok ist. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub) nennt ebenfalls zuerst den sächlichen und als Alternative den männlichen Artikel. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pub) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pub) schließen sich dem an. ...

Comment: ... Ich gebe zu, das folgende Argument hat kein großes Gewicht, aber das Wort "Pub" stammt von "public house" ab. Und weil das Haus sächlich ist, ist es nur naheliegend (aber natürlich nicht zwingend, das gebe ich zu) auch das Pub mit diesem Artikel zu versehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dasjenige deutsche Wort, dessen Bedeutung am ehesten dem *Pub* entspricht, wäre aber **die** Kneipe. Übrigens, *Beisl* musste ich erst nachschlagen, der Begriff ist mir völlig unbekannt (genaugenommen war er es bis eben und wird es voraussichtlich in wenigen Tagen wieder sein).

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Das Wort, das in Östereich am ehesten dem Pub entspricht, wäre **das** Beisl. Bei uns gibt es keine Kneipen sondern Beisln. Peter Alexander - Das kleine Beisl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAnPGArfqdg Songtext: https://www.lyrix.at/t/peter-alexander-das-kleine-beisl-4f8 Coverfoto: https://media.hitparade.ch/cover/big/peter_alexander-das_kleine_beisl_s.jpg Nachdem der Liedtext in Deutschland nicht verstanden wurde, hat Peter Alexander auch eine "Piefke-Version" mit dem Titel »die kleine Kneipe« herausgebracht, die man ihm hierzulande aber ein wenig übel nahm.

Answer (score 3):

Well, no, that can't be right (what would the phrase be in apposition to?). In linguistic circles, the grammatical status of phrases like *ihr Kerle* is not entirely clear, simply because different theoretical and terminological concepts dictate somewhat different interpretations.

- One way of looking at it is describing the whole expression as a pronominal phrase consisting of a head in the form of a personal pronoun, *ihr*, and an apposition in the form of a noun, *Kerle*. (Probably the predominant - and my prefered - way of looking at it.)
- Others insist on a terminological distinction from "ordinary" cases of apposition and consider *Kerle* "apposition-like" (eg Zifonun et al, Grammatik der deutschen Sprache, vol 3, p 2047).
- Still others dislike the qualification of *ihr* in such cases as a pronoun/proterm and analyse the phrase as a determiner phrase, with *ihr* in this case acting as a "transitive determiner". (Somewhat dubious as it seems to conflict with the ordinary understanding of determiners in German.)

Comment: No matter what the grammatical status actually is, to me the phrase seems pretty equivalent to "you guys" in English.

Comment: Sure. Similar constructions exist in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *Kerle* can be considered to be in apposition to *ihr*.

Both English and German have these kinds of appositions (of nouns to first or second person pronouns). However, as rightly pointed out by Christian Geiselmann in a comment, this particular example is probably a mistranslation.

In English, the singular and plural forms of the personal pronoun are identical in the second person: *you*. This has lead to the use of appositions, such as *you guys*, or the contraction *y'all*, as unambiguously plural forms. German has no such need: *du* and *ihr* (as well as *dich*, *dir* and *euch*) are clearly distinct.

Therefore, a sentence such as

> Don't you guys ever give up?

should never be translated as

> Gebt ihr Kerle eigentlich nie auf?

but simply as

> Gebt ihr eigentlich nie auf?

In contrast to this special use, both English and German use these appositions to characterise the person or persons being referred to:

> you fool, you idiot, you faithful servants, you brave souls …
> du Depp, ihr traurigen Gestalten, ihr munteren Gesellen …
>
> You men are all alike.
> Ihr Männer seid alle gleich.